# polygon grid into raster with arcmap

Tags: raster, arcmap, polygon, export

I have a shp file with a grid (polygons). For each cell I have the attribute "Join Count" generating during a spatial joints (It is the number of points in each cells).

I would like to export this shp file as a raster.I tried "feature to raster" but no result so far... With feature to raster tool, I set it like this:

[image]

But then as result, the raster cells are not overlapping with my grid:

[image]

In blue is the new raster generated.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your [output cell size parameter](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-to-raster.htm) to the cell size of your vector grid.

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd. I also tried to change the setting but I could not find the solution...

Comment: it has to be set on 1000 ...